# installing ruby on rails with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I tried to follow [this digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide to rails in my ubuntu 16.04 machine using rbenv.

I've finished the part till cloning both rbenv and ruby-build, but when I try to use the command `rbenv install 2.3.1`, I'm getting the following error:

```
anirudh@anirudh:/tmp$ rbenv install 2.4.0
Downloading ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20170201-12-g4e80d99)
```

I tried to download the file using `wget` and `curl` manually and am able to connect to the link. Don't know what is the problem. I've searched a lot online, but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04. this has very good documentation to install rails both using rbenv or rvm

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/855) link?
It suggests that the error is due to that version being installed already.
Another fix might be to reinstall rbenv through apt-get.

> I believe you get that error because ruby-build is already installed. Try `ruby-build --version` and it should give you a response like `ruby-build 20160112` the timestamp is for the day that you installed it.